# Automated creation of Sites and their contents

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

I am using the Office 365 Sharepoint Online and I would like to make the creation of specific Sites and their contents automated by using a template/workflow/script etc. The following image outlines the desired structure after completion:

[image: Desired Structure]

Basically user defines the `<NEW CLIENT>` and `<Project Name>` site names and the system will take care of the actual creation so the user does not have to do it manually each time. Do you have any ideas how to achieve this behaviour?

I had a look at the templates, but they are no longer supported in the Office 365 Sharepoint. Perhaps a custom script or a workflow of some kind? Thank you very much for any suggestions.

Regards,

Lukas

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at "site scripts" or SharePoint PnP (Patterns and Practices).

Answer (score 0):

A custom workflow works great in this situation (I use about 4 site creation WF on my SP site). Create a list with the fields you're asking for (Site Name, Description, etc.) and then trigger the WF when an item is created. Then, whenever a new item is added to the list, a site is created based on that info.

Here are a series of links I refer to when creating these WFs:

Use 
["Create Site From Template using SharePoint 2013 Workflow"](https://www.dmcinfo.com/latest-thinking/blog/id/8661/create-site-from-template-using-sharepoint-2013-workflow) by David Ufford to create the WF, he provides a great step-by-step.

["Gotcha on SharePoint Designer Workflows in App Step"](http://www.fabiangwilliams.com/2014/06/19/gotcha-on-sharepoint-designer-workflows-in-app-step/) by Fabian Wialliams and ["Trials or tribulation? Inside SharePoint 2013 workflows"](http://www.cleverworkarounds.com/2013/12/21/trials-or-tribulation-inside-sharepoint-2013-workflowspart-1/) by CleverWorkarounds  are great for troubleshooting. I have yet to get one of these WF to work on the first go. Usually takes a day or so (*sigh*) to get it working.

You said you looked "at the templates, but they are no longer supported," are you referring to site templates? In some cases you can still create a site template through SharePoint designer. Open the page in SharePoint Designer and get to the Homepage (first option under Site Objects in the Navigation pane). There should be an option to "Save As Template" in the ribbon under "Manage."